# Is there a punishment in hell for people who are converted to other religions?

Tags: other-religions, naraka

I want to know if there are punishments after the death of a person who have converted from Hindu to some other religion (on his own decision may be) having any punishments are waiting on the hell?

Note: This is purely my imagination question. (Not about any person or any religion.)

Comment: dharma is the path of truth and righteousness; it is not the public adherence to any particular form. You can be a person of truth and righteousness and be a person who follows a different Ishta than your own. To think in the modern terms of 'religion' is to not understand dharma. Better to be a person who follows the way of a different 'religion' and follow the path of truth and righteousness than to be a 'Hindu' in name only and not follow dharma. The Lord knows everyone's true heart.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Well said !  A good person who tries very hard to be good to others and tries to live w/ kindness respect for others, it doesn’t matter what religion they are. And a bad person doing bad stuffs is just horrid, doesn’t matter what religion they are either.